# Will Stain get One for All ability?

Tags: my-hero-academia

After watching fight between Midoriya and Stain, I started to wonder if Stain may obtain the One for All ability ?

We all know that in order to pass the ability of One for All, you need to pass your DNA to other person ( By passing hair which *All might* did, but you can use blood or saliva too ).
Now Stain always licks the blood to use his pulverise on the enemy, and he licked Midoriya's blood, too.

As now Midoriya has the One for All ability, licking his blood, and DNA there, seems like it may allow the ability to be passed to Stain?.

So is it really possible (considering Stain is unconscious/dead )?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the requirements for getting One for All is intent/will - both the person passing it on needs to want it to be passed on and the person getting it needs to want to have it.

As any fight between Stain and Midoriya would lack this component (Midoriya wouldn't ever want to pass One for All to Stain - and Stain would have to know about it *and* want it), there is no chance of Stain getting One for All.

This has been explained in the manga, which is ahead of the anime (and was likely only explained because others have figured the same loophole as you have).

Comment: I'm not sure which episodes were out by the time of this answer, but All Might explained this to Midoriya, so the anime also explains this.

Answer (score -1):

It can be forcefully passed on to someone else, but it can not be forcefully taken.

[image]

Comment: This was stated by All Might soon after in the Anime.