# Did the hero killer get deku's quirk

Tags: my-hero-academia

Like because to pass down the quirk you have to have deku's dna and he licked his blood so did toga she got a little bit of his blood too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Stain get One for All ability?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/41632/will-stain-get-one-for-all-ability)

Answer (score 3):

No, Midoriya later on asks Allmight about the same issue and he is told that the quirk can only be passed down if the user wishes to and cannot be stolen

Source:

https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Vs._Hero_Killer_Arc#The_Origin:_All_For_One_and_One_For_All